# append the text to postgres crosstab query

Tags: postgresql, pivot, postgresql-9.5

Am using below crosstab query:

```
SELECT 
    * 
from crosstab('SELECT id,task_id, status_id FROM table ORDER BY 1,2')
     AS final_result(id character varying(50), task1 int,task2 int,task3 int,task4 int)
```

Result is below:

[image]

But I want the result like below:
in place of *1* I want result as *'name'* and in place of *2* I want result as *'city'*.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Akina commented, a `CASE` statement would do. That is, unless you have many more values to resolve, in which case you would typically join to a lookup table ...

```
SELECT * 
FROM   crosstab(
  $$SELECT id, task_id, CASE WHEN status_id = 1 THEN 'name' ELSE 'city' END
    FROM   tbl
    ORDER  BY 1,2$$
, $$SELECT unnest('{1, 2, 3, 4}'::text[])$$  -- suggestion, see below
   ) AS final_result(id text, task1 text, task2 text, task3 text, task4 text);
```

Using dollar-quoting to avoid confusion with double single-quotes.

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860)

And you might want to use the safe 2-parameter form for multiple task values where any can be missing or added. Provide actual `task_id` values for the suggested addition.

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/939860)